# libgnuradio-runtime problem when capturing GNSS signals with HackRF

Tags: gnuradio

we are trying to capture GNSS signals using HackRF and gnss-sdr. We have installed gnss-sdr, gnuradio (version 3.10.1) and gr-osmosdr (version 0.2.3). When we try to run the following command $ LD_PRELOAD=/home/gnss/gnss-sdr/gr-osmosdr/build/lib/libgnuradio-osmosdr.so /home/gnss/gnss-sdr/build/src/main/gnss-sdr -c hackrf_GPS_L1.conf, we get the following error /home/gnss/gnss-sdr/build/src/main/gnss-sdr: error while loading shared libraries: libgnuradio-runtime.so.3.10.6git: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.

We don't know what could be the problem, maybe someone had the same problem?
Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

Just to document this here as well:
I answered this question on the [mailing list](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/discuss-gnuradio/2023-04/msg00048.html):

> Hi,
>
> the GR version you report to have installed (3.10.1) and the version
> of libgnuradio-runtime (3.10.6git) differ: I think you're trying to
> mix different versions of GNU Radio, and especially, try to load a
> library (libgnuradio-osmosdr.so) that was linked against a different
> version of GNU Radio with GNU Radio.
>
> That won't work. I'm not an expert in GNSS-SDR, but in all honesty,
> when methodology requires you LD_PRELOAD a single library, you're
> always trying to "bend" something around; and unless you really meant
> to replace one library with another that does something different,
> that's *usually* not what you want.
>
> So:
>
> > We don't know what could be the problem,
>
> Almost certainly that you are using LD_PRELOAD with a different
> version of GNU  Radio.
>
> Best regards, Marcus
>
> On 21.04.23 15:38, Katarina Radoš wrote:
>
> > Hi everyone,
> >
> > we are trying to capture GNSS signals using HackRF and gnss-sdr. We have installed gnss-sdr, gnuradio (version 3.10.1) and gr-osmosdr
> > (version 0.2.3). When we try to run the following command
> >
> > ```
> > $ LD_PRELOAD=/home/gnss/gnss-sdr/gr-osmosdr/build/lib/libgnuradio-osmosdr.so /home/gnss/gnss-sdr/build/src/main/gnss-sdr -c hackrf_GPS_L1.conf
> > ```
> >
> > we get the following error
> >
> > ```
> >  /home/gnss/gnss-sdr/build/src/main/gnss-sdr:
> >  error while loading shared libraries:
> >  libgnuradio-runtime.so.3.10.6git: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.
> > ```
> >
> > We don't know what could be the problem, maybe someone had the same problem? Thanks in advance for your help.
> >
> > Best regards,
> > KR